# Formatting dates and creating dummy variables for dates

Tags: r, special-characters, date-formatting

Question here from a not so experienced programmer.. I'm trying to create dummy variables indicating whether an issue was after the 15th of September 2008 (Financial Crisis). My dataset has dates formatted the following: 15-09-2008. As the variable was recognized by R as a character, I tried to transform it into a date by running the following codes:

`c$NewDate <- strptime(c$IssueDate, "&d-&m-&Y")`

`format(c$NewDate, "&Y/&m/&d")`

However, the upper code already caused the variable c$NewDate to only return NAs, whereas there were no NAs present in the dataframe c at all. I really don't understand where it's coming from.

As I said, my main goal was to create the dummy variable. I already tried the following code in the dd-mm-yy formatting: `c$GFC <- ifelse(c$IssueDate > as.Date("15-09-2008", origin = "10-01-1986"), 0, 1)`, but this does not work. It denotes an issue of 10-01-1986 with a 1 and an issue of 24-01-1986 with a zero. This thus doesn't make sense at all.. If there is any way that is faster than this to create the dummy indicating whether an issue was after 15-09-2008, I would also love to know it!

[Image showing what's going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0xBl.png)

[Image showing what's going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwwIN.png)

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the `tidyverse` and `lubridate` to handle this problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# generate the test data
temp <- data.frame(mytime = c("14-09-2008", "13-5-2021"))


temp <- 
  temp %>%
  
  # create a "tibble" object which can be operated by tidyverse package
  as_tibble() %>%
  
  # transform the format from a character into a date
  mutate(mytime = dmy(mytime)) %>%
  
  # generate indicators
  mutate(indicator = mytime <= dmy("15-09-2008") )
```

Or you only use the `lubridate` package：

```
> temp$mytime
[1] "14-09-2008" "13-5-2021" 
> date_format <- dmy(temp$mytime)
> date_format
[1] "2008-09-14" "2021-05-13"
> ifelse(date_format <= dmy("15-09-2008"), 1, 0)
[1] 1 0
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot! However, when running the mutate code, I get the following error..: `no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: The mutate function can only operate on Tibble objects. You can choose not to use this function and refer directly to the answer I just added.